# Upgrade Apache 2.4.18 to 2.4.26 or higher on Ubuntu 16.04.7

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I am trying to upgrade Apache2 to a version higher than 2.4.26 so that I can enable HTTP/2. I have run these commands with no joy:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

I have Ubuntu [ESM](https://ubuntu.com/security/esm). Ubuntu 16.04.7

Comment: Check this link out: https://gist.github.com/GAS85/990b46a3a9c2a16c0ece4e48ebce7300 _"You’ll notice that Apache 2.4.18 is the current default version for Ubuntu 16.04"_

Comment: Thanks @Jeppe, that is true, but it goes on to say to add the PPA 'ondrej/apache2' to upgrade further, which I had done before with no joy

Answer (score 2):

Some alternatives:

- Downloading the source code from https://httpd.apache.org/download.cgi and installing in a different path such as /opt/apache2 - there could be a problem with dependencies such as OpenSSL ?
- Running a Ubuntu 18.04/20.04/22.04 container with apache2 inside your Ubuntu 16.04 - not sure if docker is available in 16.04 ESM ?
- My recommendation, do-release-upgrade and move to Ubuntu 18.04 ( https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BionicUpgrades ). You will get TLS 1.3 as an extra.

Comment: Although I can't say this is the solution, it is helpful information, thank you. It sounds like I'll have to try move to Ubuntu 18.04 again; it broke the server last time I tried

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial reached [End of Standard Support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) in April 2021 and all the packages for this version of Ubuntu were removed from `ppa:ondrej/apache2` by its maintainer.

Source: https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1567

Comment: Thank you. Although I can't say this is the solution to installing a newer Apache2 version on 16.04, it does explain why the original commands no longer work

Comment: @Crimbo I believe you can try to manually install the latest version of Apache from source based on [the official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html).

Comment: Good shout. I see there is an upgrade section

Answer (score 0):

Have you run:

```
sudo apt install apache2
```

Then restart Apache.

Comment: Yeah, just tried it again `apache2 is already the newest version (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.17+esm5)`. It's like Xenial has been removed from the PAA. What I don't understand is others with 16.10 have been able to upgrade to a newer version of Apache

Comment: What is your output of:
apache2 -v

Comment: `Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu), Server built: 2022-03-17T13:34:00`

Comment: I'm tempted to manually upgrade, but I'm too worried what version works with Ubuntu 16.04 and where to get the installation files (I can't seem to find it on apache.org)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these 2 lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

1. `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/apache2/ubuntu xenial main`
2. `deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/apache2/ubuntu xenial main`

and then

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt upgrade`

`sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: Thank you, but I got lots of `...is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list` errors. I think this is effectively the same as adding the PPA 'ondrej/apache2' anyway